# Android - Using a Content Provider to send Location Provider

Tags: android, location, listener

So, I have created an android application with a Content Provider (let's call this X). I also have a mock App (that we will call Y) that asks for data from application X by using a ContentResolver and URIs.

However, by calling the query() function, the content provider returns data in a Cursor type. So, asking for location data I could provide Y with my last known location (longitude and latitude) but that's it.

The question is: Can I send back a location listener object instead, something that will keep being updated as the location changes? I already know it is not a proper practice, but I wonder if it is possible.

(I know I could skip the X application and just ask for the location from Y, but the point is using X to "extend" some of the OS capabilities.)

Right now, I extract the data inside the application X and parse them in a cursor to return them to Y. However, as soon as I return the value, I get nothing new in Y.